# Can't connect to docker database

Tags: spring, database, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I created postgresql database docker container with by following commands:

```
docker run -d --name postgresCont -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=user123 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass123 postgres
docker exec -it postgresCont bash
psql -h localhost -U user123
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

But when I want tp connect to this database from my spring application I get an error:
DBMS: PostgreSQL (no ver.)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
[28000] ERROR: In pg_hba.conf entry for host "25.35.116.65", user "user123", database "db_name", no match found.
(Specifying version didn't help also)

I tried to connect to database using localhost as well as host.docker.internal but nothing worked.
A also tried to allow in pg_hba.conf connection from all ports but it also didn't help.
What I exactly need is to connect to database with url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/db_name
Maybe I did something wrong while creating container or I just need something to fix I don't know, it's my first project and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Correct the encoding problem in your question, remove the symbols.